# How can axios-mock-adapter return an object on GET request?

Tags: node.js, get, axios-mock-adapter

There's a block of code that uses axios-mock-adapter and returns an object via a GET request:

```
mock.onGet('/api/auth').reply((config) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(config.data);
    const {email, password} = data;

    const user = _.cloneDeep(authDB.users.find(_user => _user.data.email === email));

    const error = {
        email   : user ? null : 'Check your username/email',
        password: user && user.password === password ? null : 'Check your password'
    };

    if ( !error.email && !error.password && !error.displayName )
    {
        delete user['password'];

        const access_token = jwt.sign({id: user.uuid}, jwtConfig.secret, {expiresIn: jwtConfig.expiresIn});

        const response = {
            "user"        : user,
            "access_token": access_token
        };

        return [200, response];
    }
    else
    {
        return [200, {error}];
    }
});
```

User is a JSON object with various amounts of values. How is this possible? What would it look like in the URL? I'm studying the code block to learn how to do it without axios-mock-adapter.

Comment: "How is this possible?" - What exactly? "What would it look like in the URL?" - Something like `.get('/api/auth')`?

Comment: I meant the parameters. I thought Get requests looked something like 'api/auth/?bar=foo&lorem=ipsum&...".

Comment: Well the mock adapter is designed to respond to requests of the form mentioned in the url, with or without params. So a get request with params will be caught in the above block and response returned according to the logic in the block.